# Delay repetitive javascript code

Tags: javascript, facebook, instagram, sleep

Long story short, I'm trying to automate some of the action on the social sites I'm using (Facebook, Instagram etc). For example adding friends, liking posts and so on, like clicking each Follow button after a few seconds delay as in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugtsH.png)

I have the following script I'd like to use in the browser's console (not working, testing in Chrome):

```
var clikker = document.getElementsByClassName('_qv64e _gexxb _4tgw8 _njrw0');

for(var i=0;i<clikker.length;i++){

    function sleep (time) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
    }

    sleep(5000).then(() => {
    clikker[i].click();

    });
}
```

I thought this should work. Any improvement to get it done is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: try `for(let i=0` etc

Comment: You know it will break all the time? The classes `_qv64e` `_gexxb` `_4tgw8` and `_njrw0` will change. Also Facebook doesn't allow you to do it. You have to use the API.

Comment: why would anyone want to automate following, adding friends or liking posts anyway? not to mention that it´s not allowed, what wizkid commented already. i mean, friends are selected manually, if you know them or if you really want to connect with them. it´s not like you would want to mass-friendlist, right? that would be weird.

Comment: If it wasn't allowed, they wouldn't have suggested tons of 'friends' to follow. Also, Google and Mozilla would have banned extensions that can do this in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Why would Google and Mozilla ban extensions just because they go against Facebook Terms of Service?

Answer (score 0):

you can try wrapping your for loop in an if statement

```
if(clikker.length){
console.log(clikker);

    for(var i=0;i<clikker.length;i++){

        function sleep (time) {
            return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
        }

        sleep(5000).then(() => {
        clikker[i].click();

        });
    }
}
```

it could be that your array is returning 0 or undefined. Always check to see the contents of the array.

Comment: No, the problem is that by the time `clickker[i].click()` is called the loop has finished and the value of i is clickker.length so `clickker[i]` is undefined. Following code `for(var i=0;i<5;i++){setTimeout(_=>console.log(i),20);}` will log 5, 5 times. But when you pass a function with a closure of `i` at the time of creation then it will log 0,1,2,3,4: `for(var i=0;i<5;i++){setTimeout((newI=>_=>console.log(newI))(i),20);}` Best is to avoid loops with asynchronous handling and use Array.prototype methods.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a closure of variable `i` in an asynchronous function handler. By the time your resolve handler is called the loop has finished and the value of `i` is the length of clicker

You can use the `forEach` method of a `NodeList` which is the return type of `querySelectorAll` and then use `setTimeout` (no promise needed):

```
document.querySelectorAll('_qv64e _gexxb _4tgw8 _njrw0')
.forEach(
  (element,index)=>
    setTimout(
      _=>element.click(),
      (index+1)*5000
    )
)
```

Comment: For Instagram, I get this error in the logs "POST https://graph.instagram.com/logging_client_events net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT", every the script triggers. However, this seems to work just fine (it clicks all buttons at once, though) "var clikker = document.getElementsByClassName('_qv64e _gexxb _4tgw8 _njrw0');

for(var i=0;i<clikker.length;i++){
 clikker[i].click();
}"